# Passing a Python List of Strings as Dynamic Variable in String

Tags: python, sql, string

I cannot figure out why this is not working. I'm trying to pass a list of strings as part of a loop inside a string that is used as database query. This is the error I'm getting:

```
\porfiler03.ar.local\gtdshare\vortex\monthly_variability\scripts\wind_index_chinook_region_3plots_working_monthly.py:71 in get_db_data
    crs_obj.execute(query)

UndefinedColumn: column "east" does not exist
LINE 5: ...s_name = 'UNITED STATES'  AND maint_region_name = EAST  AND ...
```

Here is the code:

```
regions = ['EAST','CENTRAL']

for x in regions:
    randall_query = f"""select plant_mos_adj_wind.plant_name, plant_mos_adj_wind.business_name,plant_mos_adj_wind.business_code,plant_mos_adj_wind.wind_speed_ms,
    plant_mos_adj_wind.maint_region_name, plant_mos_adj_wind.wind_direction_deg, plant_mos_adj_wind.mos_time, plant_mos_adj_wind.total_current_capacity,
    plant_mos_adj_wind.dataset
    from vortex.plant_mos_adj_wind
    where business_name = 'UNITED STATES'  AND maint_region_name = {x}  AND dataset = 'ERA5'"""
    try:
       connection = psycopg2.connect(user="cms_app",
                                      password="xxxxx",
                                      host="frupaapg02.ar.local",
                                      port="xxxx",
                                      database="xxxx")
       print("Selecting rows from vortex plant_mos_adj_wind table using cursor.fetchmany")
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       cdata = get_db_data(cursor, randall_query, False, True).round(1) #panda df
       postgreSQL_select_Query = f"""select plant_name, business_name, maint_region_name, total_current_capacity, mos_time, wind_speed_ms, wind_direction_deg, dataset
       from vortex.plant_mos_adj_wind
       where business_name = 'UNITED STATES' AND maint_region_name = {x}  AND dataset = 'ERA5'"""
    
       cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
       chinookmos_records = cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        #closing database connection.
        if(connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
    
    #iterate the columns
            print("Column headers for cdata are:")
            for col in cdata.columns:
                print(col)
```

This should work using the f string function and substituting for x in regions but you can see that it fails because of the EAST argument and it clearly should be 'EAST' passes as a string is my thought.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Comment: The f-string just doesn't work this way. The actual string is `EAST` (no quotes) and is inserted as it is.

Comment: try adding quotes around `{x}` , like this `... AND maint_region_name = '{x}' ...` So when `EAST` gets inserted into the string it looks like `'EAST'` on the  SQL Query.

Comment: `EAST` looks like a column name at the moment as it is not in quotes

Comment: yes!!! '{x}' works by adding the single quotes. thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 2 solutions:

1. Remove tabs of for loop in query line after 1st query line

`randall_query = f"""select plant_mos_adj_wind.plant_name, plant_mos_adj_wind.business_name,plant_mos_adj_wind.business_code,plant_mos_adj_wind.wind_speed_ms, plant_mos_adj_wind.maint_region_name, plant_mos_adj_wind.wind_direction_deg, plant_mos_adj_wind.mos_time, plant_mos_adj_wind.total_current_capacity, plant_mos_adj_wind.dataset from vortex.plant_mos_adj_wind where business_name = 'UNITED STATES'  AND maint_region_name = {x}  AND dataset = 'ERA5'"""`

2. Check whether column name EAST exists or not in database.

Comment: it definitely does exist in the db.

Answer (score 0):

f string just puts value of variable in string so you need to add single quotes('') to {x}.

Convert this
AND maint_region_name = {x}

to this:
AND maint_region_name = '{x}'